# Integrated webcam on a Dell V131 drains the battery when not used. How to turn it off?

Tags: 12.10, power-management, webcam, battery, powertop

After using the integrated webcam, it never fully turns off and keeps hogging the battery. From `powertop`:

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 22.6 W
The estimated remaining time is 0 hours, 41 minutes

Summary: 369.6 wakeups/second,  60.7 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 7.9% CPU use

            Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
          100.0%                      Device         USB device: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD (CN0T3NPC724871BBK5P1A00)
           11.8%                      Device         Display backlight
            5.7 ms/s      58.1        Process        /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

How can I properly turn it off? All the tunables are "good."

It's a [Dell V131](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201105-8049/). I don't know about the camera. This is the only device I cannot account for in `lsusb` output:

```
# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
**Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2880 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.**
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/747212/how-to-disable-integrated-webcam-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install TLP and it will do it automatically for you. www.linrunner.de

Comment: I would prefer a simpler solution but tlp worked. Thanks.