# How to disable integrated webcam on ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, dell, webcam

I have a notebook `Dell Inspiron` Model `14 3437-A30` and in my gtalk appears that the camera is turned on and is automatically turned on, but the light is not on. Also, unfortunately there is no keyboard shortcut.

I tried to use the `cheese` program, but it only activates the webcam.

I feel that my webcam is being automatically turned on without turning on the light.

How do I disable my webcam so the gtalk not show that my webcam is turned on? or how to make my webcam is not automatically activated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to find the driver for your webcam and unload it. I don't have Dell Inspirion so I don't know what driver you have for webcam. Try to find it with

```
lsmod
```

In my case it was `uvcvideo`. When you find it unload it. In my case the command was:

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
```

After I removed it, the cheese did not find the device any more and it couldn't work. Then try to load it again. In my case the command was

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

If your driver is not uvcvideo replace it in the commands with your driver name. Make a test too to see that your application does not load the driver. It is a small possibility for that also because root privileges are required to load kernel modules.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @nobody, was exactly that I needed!

Answer (score 7):

Instead of disabling the `uvcvideo` driver (which disables all the webcams), you can also disable one webcam and keep all the others functional. For that:

1. Find out the device string of the webcam you want to disable:

   ```
   for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do 
     echo $device; cat $device; 
   done
   ```

   This will show result lines like this:

   ```
   /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.6/product
   Integrated Camera
   ```

   In which case the device string we look for is `1-1.6`.
2. Disable the webcam using your device string in a command like this:

   ```
   echo '1-1.6' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
   ```
3. To enable your webcam at a later time, use your device string in a command like this:

   ```
   echo '1-1.6' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
   ```

For more details, see: "[Disabling the Webcam or USB Ports on Linux](http://karlcode.owtelse.com/blog/2017/01/09/disabling-usb-ports-on-linux/)".

Comment: Nice guide! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative command to `rmmod` you can use this to disable the camera until reboot:

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
```

And if you get the error message: modprobe: FATAL: Module uvcvideo is in use, you can try to force its removal with `rmmod` using the `-f` parameter:

```
sudo rmmod -f uvcvideo
```

To enable your webcam back again, type:

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```