# 17.10 Integrated webcam draining battery?

Tags: power-management, battery, webcam

My autonomy recently dropped to almost 1/3rd of what it used to be. Opening Powertop I see this:
[image: powertop]

I never used the integrated webcam. Disabling it with `modprobe -r uvcvideo` does not work.

**How do I investigate this problem further?**

Comment: How old is that battery? They don't last forever.

Comment: @MichaelBay not really old, and until two days ago it lasted up to 7 hours. Power usage was on 7W usually.

Comment: Try disabling the integrated webcam. https://askubuntu.com/questions/747212/how-to-disable-integrated-webcam-on-ubuntu